# Why is my Ubuntu server not sending emails from my website visitors through PHP?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

I have hosted my website on my Ubuntu server. I have added an email forum on my website so visitors can send emails to me. But it is not working anymore. Here's the full php code

```
<?php 
    $errors = '';
    $myemail ='my@email.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];  


    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Username: $name \n  $email_address \n Password: \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: example.com/thanks.html');
?>
```

Comment: Where is this Ubuntu server?   If it is hosted at home, your ISP likely blocks directly sent outbound mail.   In that case you will have to configure your computer as "smarthost".   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail/282579

Comment: It is a VPS in Digital Ocean

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons.   Find the log files and see what they say.

Comment: This belongs at Stack Overflow but is a very common duplicate question there so I won't migrate it. You can view the canonical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail) which contains instructions for debugging this.